# Wrapping "C++ dll" in "C++/CLI" when function returns pointer to abstract class

Tags: c#, visual-c++, c++-cli, clr, wrapper

I have c++ dll:
UnmanagedCode.h looks like:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
struct Class1
{
 public: virtual void method() = 0;
};
extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) Class1* Create_function();
```

UnmanagedCode.cpp looks like:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "UnmanagedCode.h"
class Class2 : Class1
{
 public: void method(){}
};

Class1* Create_function()
{
 Class2* c2 = new Class2(); // I don't care about free memory for this  example
 Class1* c1 = (Class1*)c2;
 return c1;
};
```

I have c++/cli managed class:

```
    #include "Library.h"
    #include "UnmanagedCode.h"
    typedef Class1* (*Createfunction)();
    namespace CLIWrapper
    {
    public ref class ManagedClI
    {
      private:
        Class1* cl1;
      public:
        ManagedClI(){}
        void Create()
        {   
            //some usual routine for loading c++ library with Library class
            String ^path = "path to the library.dll"; // just to show
            using System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal;
            const char* cpath = (const char*)(Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(path)).ToPointer();
            Library loader;
            loader.load((string)cpath, false);
            Marshal::FreeHGlobal(System::IntPtr((void*)cpath)); 
            Createfunction hDet = (Createfunction)loader.getProcAddress("Create_function"); 
            cl1 = hDet();
            cl1->method();  // if I call cl1->method() here it works perfect!!      
        }

        void SomeFunction()
        {           
           cl1->method();    //but if I call cl1->method() here it throws an error!!!
        }
    };
    }
```

I use ManagedClI class in my c# application, Something like:

```
CLIWrapper.ManagedClI object = new CLIWrapper.ManagedClI();
object.Create();
object.SomeFunction(); // <- this causes an error
```

`object.SomeFunction()` causes the error: attempted to read or write protected memory when it calls `cl1->method()`.
But in the same time `cl1->method()` is normally working in `Object.Create()`.

I think that I'm doing something wrong when wrapping `Create_function()`.
Can anyone suggest something?

Comment: A guess (I am no C++/cli C++ C# interop expert) but what I'd look into was if `loader` going out of scope causes the `Library` object to unload the dll.  Which unloads the virtual function table, and causes your problem?  It would at least explain symptoms, and is easy to check: store the `Library` object in your `ManagedCLI` class rather than locally.

Comment: Also, never ever use `Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi`.  C++/CLI comes with the `marshal_as<std::string>` helper template that works a thousand times better.

Comment: @BenVoigt actually this was just for example but thx anyway =) but Loader was the real thing.

Comment: Native code never needs a lot of help to corrupt the heap, you showing us a stack trace when it bombs is pretty essential to have to stop guessing.  You are making one mistake in your code, the C++/CLI compiler cannot tell that these declarations are for native code and uses the __cdecl calling convention.  You need to wrap the #include and the typedef with #pragma managed(push, off) and #pragma managed(pop).

Comment: @HansPassant I use `#pragma managed` and `#pragma unmanaged` in my real project to wrap such things. But yes, maybe it's better to `managed(push, off) /  managed(pop)`. I'm new to c++/cli, just learning through coding.

Comment: Hmm, you expect us to diagnose a nasty problem from completely fake source code.  That's not going to work of course.

Comment: @HansPassant the real code is very big to show and difficult to explain, i'm glad that "shown code" was enough in the end.

Comment: @felix you got lucky.  To avoid relying on luck, what you do is create a toy project, and try to reproduce your problem with 'sample' code like the above.  Once you have it reproduced, you know you did not leave anything important out, because you verified it.

Comment: @Yakk I did it with this sample class that was shown and got the same error  - so almost no luck!

Comment: @Felix did `cl1->method()` work *inside* the loading code function? Because if your calling convention was wrong, it shouldn't have worked.  And Hans pointed out that the sample code above did not set the calling convention right?

Comment: @Yakk agreed. For shown example, c++ dll was build with default  (`__cdecl `) calling convention (set in VS c++ compiler properties), so `cl1->method()` worked inside the loading code function. Also agreed on Hans suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Library loader` is more than just a loader.  It is the CLI object that keeps the DLL loaded.  When the last reference to it goes away and it is cleaned up, the DLL is unloaded.

The virtual function table of your abstract class lives in that DLL, as does the functions that it points to.  When the DLL is unloaded, that virtual function table becomes invalid, and attempting to call the method is going to be undefined behavior.

To fix this in a first approximation, store the `Library` object in your `ManagedClI` class instead of as a local variable.